# section headings happen to be the last line on a page - how to fix that?

Tags: microsoft-word-2007, typography

I am using Word 2007 under Windows XP.

Often, a section heading (styles like "Heading 2", Heading 3") happen to be the last line on a page. This looks very ugly and destroys the logical flow of a document.

Can I fix this somehow, preferrably *not* manually?

Manually inserting a page break right before the offending section heading is not a solution, because I might enter text later somewhere upstream in the document, and then there would be a superfluous page break.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using the built-in heading styles, you shouldn't have this problem because they are set to `Keep with next` by default. If that's failing or you're using a custom style, here're the steps to enable the proper behavior:

1. Select the paragraph you need by double-clicking on the left margin next to it (the cursor changes to a mirror-reflection of itself when moved into the margin).
2. Open the paragraph option dialog by clicking the button in the lower-right of the paragraph section on Home tab of the Ribbon:
   [image]
3. In the `Line and Page Breaks` tab of the dialog, make sure that `Keep with next` is checked:
   [image]
4. Click `OK`.

Comment: Thank you works great. I am using the built-in heading styles, and keep with next is not enabled by default. Can I somehow enable this for *all* headings? Because it is very tedious to do every time this problem pops up.

Answer (score 1):

To apply this automatically to all headings within the document you have to edit the styles. (This was done with Word 2010 on Windows 7)

1. On the Home tab click the button in the lower-right of the Styles section:
   [image]
2. In the Styles window that appears click on the "Manage Styles" button:
   [image]
3. In the Manage Styles window that appears, click on Heading 1 in the "Select a style to edit" list and then click on the "Modify..." button:
   [image]
4. Once the Modify Style window appears, click on the "Format" button near the bottom of the window and choose "Paragragh...". Then choose the "Keep with next" option as described in [dnbrv's answer](https://superuser.com/a/387523/236843).

This should update the setting for all headings that are either Heading 1 or based on Heading 1.